# Django - Exclude superuser from LDAP auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, ldap

I've integrated LDAP authentication to my application using this package:

[django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/)

I also created a superuser using django command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I want to be able to to exclude this particular superuser from LDAP auth.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this exact thing.  In order to use both the LDAP and Django default authentication, I included this code in my settings file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
)
```

Is your app automatically adding existing users to LDAP?  If not, this should work fine.

Comment: aaa so i just add regular django auth backend into it. Cool thanks!